# Condition for subsetting data in R using %in%

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm doing some subsetting using `subset()` but having some issues with using the `%in%` command for my logical statement.

Consider a simple data structure like

```
  x11  x21 x12  x22
1  19 2000  32 2004
2  19 2000  20 2001
```

I want a subset where it is true that `x12` is either equal to `x22-x21+x11` or equal to `x22-x21+x11+1`.* For the example above, I want the second row, since the logical statement should evaluate to `TRUE` if and only if `x12` is 20 or 21, which is satisfied. For this simple setup, the following works for me:

```
> test1 <- data.frame(x11=c(19, 19), x21=c(2000, 2000), x12=c(32, 20), x22=c(2004, 2001))
> subset(test1, (x12 %in% c(x22-x21+x11, x22-x21+x11+1)))
  x11  x21 x12  x22
2  19 2000  20 2001
```

The problem arises when I introduce additional rows. Adding just one row:

```
  x11  x21 x12  x22
1  19 2000  32 2004
2  19 2000  20 2001
3  30 1998  32 2000
```

Now, I would like to subset this so that I get rows two and three. But using the same subset strategy as above:

```
> test2 <- data.frame(x11=c(19, 19, 30), x21=c(2000, 2000, 1998), x12=c(32, 20, 32), x22=c(2004, 2001, 2000))
> subset(test2, (x12 %in% c(x22-x21+x11, x22-x21+x11+1)))
  x11  x21 x12  x22
1  19 2000  32 2004
2  19 2000  20 2001
3  30 1998  32 2000
```

So now I get the row which I did not get in the first example. My guess is that it is related to the vector which `x12` is allowed to be in, i.e. `c(x22-x21+x11, x22-x21+x11+1)`, but I'm not sure how to construct this so that it is implied to be "row-wise" and not one vector for all rows.

Ideas are much appreciated!

---

*x11 is the age of an individual at time point x21, and x12 is the age of a (possibly different) individual at time point x22. I want the subset containing the rows in which the age (x11) at x21 is logically and physically compatible with the age (x12) at x22; an individual who is 19 in 2000 is either 19, 20 or 21 in 2001 depending on birthdays (but I discard the possibility of the individual being the same age here, for other reasons). Thus, the first row, in which we have age 19 in the year 2000, and age 32 at 2004, is not possible for the same individual.

Comment: `which the age difference is possible` - Do you mean to check if `x12` is  *between* `x22-x21+x11` and `x22-x21+x11+1`?

Comment: @zx8754 It seems like I dropped some parts of the sentence there, I've edited my post so that it makes more sense (I hope).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, beware of floating point precision limits.  If your values are all integers, this doesn't matter, but in the general case `x==y` can fail unless you use tools like `all.equal` .
Now, rather than mucking with `subset` or `%in%`, just write a conditional:

```
foo <- test1[(test1[,3]==(test1[,1]-test1[,2]+test1[,4])) |
               (test1[,3]==(test1[,1]-test1[,2]+test1[,4]+1)), ]
```

You may need to run `apply` on a row-by-row basis.

Comment: This seems to do well, but do you know (off the top of your head) if it is advisable to use this for large matrices? Or given such a use, should I alter it in some way?

Comment: I suspect using the  `<-[` operator is the faster way to go. You might want to do some time trials.

Comment: I used this in my code, but there were some errors in your answer (missing parentheses and plus signs instead of minus signs). For future reference, it should read `foo <-  test1[(test1[,3]==(test1[,1]-test1[,2]+test1[,4])) | (test1[,3]==(test1[,1]-test1[,2]+test1[,4]+1)), ]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#data
test2 <- data.frame(x11=c(19, 19, 30),
                    x21=c(2000, 2000, 1998),
                    x12=c(32, 20, 32),
                    x22=c(2004, 2001, 2000))
#range pre-computed
test2$in1 <- test2$x22-test2$x21+test2$x11
test2$in2 <- test2$x22-test2$x21+test2$x11+1

#subset
test2[ test2$x12 >= test2$in1 &
         test2$x12 <= test2$in2,]
#   x11  x21 x12  x22 in1 in2
# 2  19 2000  20 2001  20  21
# 3  30 1998  32 2000  32  33
```

Comment: This also seems to work well, but I'll ask what I asked Carl Witthoft above: would it be unwise to use this for large matrices as well, or ought I change it in some way?

Comment: Essentially same as my solution -- great minds etc :-)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft If needed I will merge to your answer, I just couldn't make your code work, plus you are using `|` operator. Also, that 1 upvote was from  me :)

Comment: No, keep your answer, especially as mine's unproven.  I think I used OR where you used AND but then the relations (> vs ==, etc) differ to match.